# Не могу выполнить PDO::exec запрос через аякс

Tags: php, pdo

Не могу вызвать выполнить запрос через PDO.

Создал подключение:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users', $u, $p);
```

А потом пытаюсь выполнить запрос:

```
 PDO::exec($str);
```

Аяксом пытаюсь его выполнить.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',             
   ...                  
    success: function (data) { 
        ...
    },
    error: function () {
         //попадаю сюда
    }               
});
```

И получаю ошибку c http кодом 500.

Comment: Смотрите что в логах

Comment: @tutankhamun а логи где смотреть? у меня wamp стоит

Comment: Беда с этими *AMPами. Вы даже не смотрите что устанавливаете и как это настроено. Ищите конфиг апача, в нем строку, кодержащую ErrorLog. По хорошему еще бывает настроено в php.ini в директиве error_log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего потому, что вы вызываете метод статический.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users', $user, $pass);
$db->exec($query);
```